# Plugin or mod for wordpress to make content publication SUPER easy

Tags: plugins, php, admin

Well, im making a wordpress web page for my dad, a psychiatrist, who barely knows how to check his email. He wants to put content regulary but the actual admin interface of wordpress is way to complex for him (i mean he does not care about comments, statistics, plugins, updates, and all the bunch of stuff wordpress comes with). Im a senior PHP developer and I can make a super easy interface but I wonder if there is not something already made?... It will be ideal something like:

Login page -> Title -> Content -> send button -> done.

If the solution is too technical dont worry, i can handle, I just dont want to make everything from 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want him to see the admin stuff, don't make him an admin, create an author account for him.

He can use the quickpress dashboard widget to add posts from the dashboard. You can [remove the other dashboard widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced%3a_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets) so it's the only one there.

You can also use [`remove_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) to remove any unnecessary admin menu items.

Answer (score 4):

You can also redirect him to `post-new.php` on login, and remove all unnecessary metaboxes from the Screen Options, and choose one column for the Screen Layout.

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_post_new', 10, 1);
function redirect_to_post_new($redirect) {
    return admin_url('post-new.php');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Milo's answer regarding the user role:

The plugin [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) is *really* handy for hiding WordPress backend interface elements. Works at *user role* level and fits the exact scenario described in the Question.

Its author is a WP heavy-weight and a regular fellow here in WPSE.

At some moment, I should do a review using the new feature from the Repository, summing up all I've [written about it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:12615%20adminimize) here in this Stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Svbtle theme https://github.com/gravityonmars/wp-svbtle

Content is either an idea ( draft ) or public ( published )

Or http://p2theme.com/ Once he's logged in he should never have to visit the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

There are also simple desktop applications that allow publishing to WordPress. You'd have to do a google search and a bit of research on your own; I've never used them so can't suggest one.

If he's familiar and comfortable with MS Office he could even write and publish his posts from within Word. I've used this successfully for clients who were terrified of the WordPress admin panel but had no problem writing an 'article' in MS Word.

If you do not have MS Office, you can use their free tool Windows Live Writer which makes it very easy to publish content.

Comment: Thanks to @kidakaka for pointing out Windows Live Writer. Another tool to add to the arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

easy way?  No - not out of the box.

However, you could create an easy way.  Can he use Excel?  One way I used recently was to allow a client to publish content by putting an XLS file in a folder - which a script turns into posts inside WordPress (which means they never have to login).  You can see that in action here (script is at bottom of the page):
http://www.wphub.com/tutorials/wordpress-import-export-tricks-xls-csv-and-plugins/

I made it even easier for the same client, just today gave them the ability to "email it to the website". I setup an email account, and wrote a script with php imap to check the box for messages, save the XLS files (to the folder for the last script) and then auto-publish.  That's about as easy as it gets!

There's also a plugin called "Post via dropbox" that does something similar with a text file:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-via-dropbox/

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a premium plugin, but you could very easily create a 'Create Post' form with [Gravityforms](http://www.gravityforms.com/). That should do it.

And, of course, a Frontend-Login with a redirect to this Frontend-Page.